# Minimum recommended hardware check failed

Tags: technical-issues, grand-theft-auto-v

I was playing GTA 5 on my Windows 10 PC (lenovo 300) with Intel and AMD Graphics.

Before I was seeing in the Control Panel that I have 2 graphics cards, but after I re-installed windows 10 from a Disk, I am seeing that I just have one graphics card. I think it's Intel.

Whenever I try to open GTA 5 it gives me this error

> minimum recommended hardware check failed

Comment: If you've re-installed windows, you likely need to [re-install graphics drivers](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download).

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-install your graphics accelerator drivers.  Lenovo's site for this is [here.](http://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/300-series/300-15isk/downloads)  From the looks of it, you'll have Win7 or Win8.1 drivers to choose from, but either should work.   You'll want to go through your laptop vendor for your drivers; AMD and nVidia cards in laptops are rarely discrete cards on a reference board, and are usually just chipsets embedded in a custom motherboard.